# Objec to Array JSON no JQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an object:

```
tracks  […]
albums  {…}
artists {…}

{"4rF7c8zpCKzuSXohs2HIpA":{"name":"Steven Universe","href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4rF7c8zpCKzuSXohs2HIpA"},
"57YFNq46Xx86nl7ETkd1Ei":{"name":"Zach Callison","href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/57YFNq46Xx86nl7ETkd1Ei"}
```

It contains more of those objects/arrays above.
How do I call them within the code so I get an array with the information?

If I can get help with that, then I can probably sort out the others too.

I am trying to grab the originalData.name to get the name values in the object, but it won't work.

```
fetch('my_url')
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
        var myObj = myJson // Is a Javascript object containing albums, artist & tracks.
        console.log(myJson)
        var artists = myObj.artists;
        var artistsString = JSON.stringify(artists);
        console.log(artists)
        console.log(artistsString)

        var originalData = JSON.parse(artistsString)
        console.log(originalData)
        console.log(originalData.name)


    });
```

I expect to see the name values in an array, which I can then sort.

Comment: `var myObj = myJson // Is a Javascript object...` If it's an object, than it's not JSON, hence the parameter shouldn't be named `myJson`.

Comment: It's my first introduction to using JSON, got it as an assignment.
Sorry for that. Not too sure what to say.

Comment: I can't understand what is your expected output.. can you please explain it?

Comment: I am trying to get an array of the artists names in JS. That way I can sort through them however I like, alphabetically, for example.

Comment: Please create a minimum verifiable complete example following the instructions in the help center. Currently your question does not include enough information to be answerable, and will almost certainly be closed if left in its current state.

Answer (score 0):

According to your JSON. Something like this I guess

```js
const rawData = {
  0: {
    artist: "Some name",
    track: "Some track"
  },
  1: {
    artist: "Some name - 2",
    track: "Some track - 2"
  }
};

const artists = Object.values(rawData).map(obj => obj.artist);
console.log(artists);
```